# Slow loading of images with new code

Tags: html, css, webkit

I've recently added some new code to my tumblr blog's html. Normally the images will scroll over fluently, but with the new code it doesn't anymore. The new code adds an effect that the images go from greyscale to normal. This is the code:

```
.post {
    -webkit-filter: grayscale(100%);
    z-index: -9999999999999999999999999px;
    -webkit-transition: all 0.5s ease-in-out;
    -moz-transition: all 0.5s ease-in-out;
    -o-transition: all 0.5s ease-in-out;
    -ms-transition: all 0.5s ease-in-out;
    transition: all 0.5s ease-in-out;
}
.post:hover {
    -webkit-filter: grayscale(0%);
    z-index: -9999999999999999999999999px;
    -webkit-transition: all 0.5s ease-in-out;
    -moz-transition: all 0.5s ease-in-out;
    -o-transition: all 0.5s ease-in-out;
    -ms-transition: all 0.5s ease-in-out;
    transition: all 0.5s ease-in-out;
}
```

[truelions.tumblr.com](http://truelions.tumblr.com)

Depending on the browser, the fault is different.
Chrome: posts "stick" for a bit while scrolling
Safari: posts are loading correctly, but feels slow. Is this because of safari 7.0 maybe?

Can someone please look at it for me, if needed more code I will supply.

Thanks.

Comment: Probably has to do more with the size of your images and all of content trying to load. Maybe a little to resource heavy.

Comment: Why is that -9999999999999999999999999px? I supposed z-index should be an integer like 999 (no "px" and avoid negative numbers)

Comment: Thanks for your thoughts, with removing the "px" part the banner disappears. Seems like it is going behind the pictures.